# adequate polling rate for a single client application

Tags: http, polling, plc

Hey im currently working at a web-HMI for an PLC-Program.
Basically when its done there will be one web-panel from where the program is controlled.

The PLC only supports simple HTTP-Requests, but no Websocket, Server Sided Events etc are available. So for any "live-data" i need to poll the data. I know polling is bad and it should be avoided, but i cant in this case.

And in general when polling i know one should be careful about the polling rate, because one should not carelessly clog up the network for the server. But in my case the "network" lies on a single Ethernet-cable (Profinet) and no other requests are going out to the server.

So how could i manage to "calculate" a optimal polling rate?